# List all local administrator accounts excluding domain admin and local admin

Tags: powershell, account, administrator

```psh
function get-localgroupmember {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
  )

  BEGIN {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
  }

  PROCESS{
    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
      $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer
      $idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
      $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')
      $group.Members |
        select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName
    } # end foreach
  } # end PROCESS
}

"Win12R2", "W12SUS" | get-localgroupmember
```

What I want is the output to look like the following and I want to flag the users in the admin group that are NOT part of our standard setup. Really I want to ignore the SAM accounts that are the domain accounts but flagging them for now works. What is happening is there is a looping through the SAM accounts to create this output. However when the machine is offline I need to note that too.

[image: EXample Output]

I also do NOT want to use a `ValueFromPipeline` but rather get a list of PC names from this command `$allComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter  'PasswordLastSet -ge $date' -properties PasswordLastSet | select Name` and then use that variable as the source to loop through.

This is my revised code but I'm having issues creating a custom object to add to an array when there seems to be looping in the `$group.Members |select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName`

```psh
function get-localgroupmember {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter PC")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [object]$computername = $null   
  )

  BEGIN {
    $newArray = @();
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
  }

  PROCESS{
    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
      If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer.name -Quiet -Count 1) {
        try {
          $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer.name
          $idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
          $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')

          $group.Members | select @{N='Server'; E={$computer.name}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName

          $objComputer = [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer.name
            Domain = $group.Members | select @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}
            Account = $Computer.samaccountName
          }
        } catch {
          $objComputer = [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer.name
            Domain = "Error"
            Account = "Error"
          }
        }
      } else {
          $objComputer = [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer.name
            Domain = "Off-Line"
            Account = "Off-Line"
          }
      } $arrayNew += $objComputer
    } # end foreach
  } # end PROCESS

  return $arrayNew
}

$date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)

$allComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter  'PasswordLastSet -ge $date' -properties PasswordLastSet | select Name

get-localgroupmember -computername $allComputers | Out-GridView
```

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers thank you for the source formatting! How did you do that? I'm now and just learning.

Comment: The code for it is `<!-- language: lang-psh -->`. Seems to like to have a blank line separating it from anything else, so I'd put it up top, put a blank under it, and then do your post. `<!-- Language-all: lang-psh -->` should work too, but I have just started using the first one whenever needed.

Comment: I had to do something almost exactly like this for a software license audit recently. Let me see if I can sift through it to tweak one thing for what you want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I would not try to output an array object like you are. There is really no need for it. Just create each object as needed, and let it output directly (you really don't need to use `return` as the function will pass any output down the pipeline unless you specifically tell it otherwise, with something like `Write-Host`, or `Out-File`). Also, it looks like your input wants an object (that's pretty vague), but you are then trying to loop through that object, and use each record as the name of a PC, so what you really want for input is an array of strings. In that case change your type from `[object]` to `[string[]]`. Lastly, a good bit of your code can be simplified if you just expand the `Name` property when creating your `$AllComputers` variable. Oh, I lied, this is the last thing... Your `return` statement is not in a valid section of your function. It would need to be something like `END{ Return $arrayNew }`

Then you just have to add a list of excepted accounts to not flag, or add some logic in, or something. Honestly, your code should do pretty much everything you want it to do with a little syntax fixing. Here's based on your script, where it outputs all members of the group and flags any that arn't a local account with the name 'Administrator', and are not a domain account listed as OK (defined in the `BEGIN` section, currently "Domain Admins" or "Workstation Admin").

```psh
function get-localgroupmember {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter PC")]
    [string[]]$computername
  )

  BEGIN {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
    $OKAccounts = ("Workstation Admin","Domain Admins" | ForEach{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
  }

  PROCESS{
    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
      If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
        try {
          $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer
          $idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
          $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')

          $group.Members | select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName, @{N='Flag';E={If(!(($_.Context.Name -eq $Computer -and $_.samaccountname -match "Administrator") -or ($_.context.name -ne $Computer -and $_.samaccountname -match $OKAccounts))){"X"}}}

        } catch {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Domain = "Error"
            SamAccountName = "Error"
            Flag = ''
          }
        }
      } else {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Domain = "Off-Line"
            SamAccountName = "Off-Line"
            Flag = ''
          }
      } 

    } # end foreach
  } # end PROCESS

}

$date = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)

$allComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter  'PasswordLastSet -ge $date' -properties PasswordLastSet | select -Expand Name
#$allComputers = $env:COMPUTERNAME
get-localgroupmember -computername $allComputers | Out-GridView
```

That should give you output something like:

```psh
Server         Domain                     SamAccountName             Flag
------         ------                     --------------             ----
TMTsLab        TMTsLab                    Administrator                  
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          Domain Admins                  
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          SomeAcct1                  X   
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          SomeAcct2                  X   
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          TMTech                     X
```

Probably better yet would be to filter out the accounts you don't want, rather than just not flag them. So change the `@{N='Flag';E={If(!(($_.Context.Name -eq $Computer -and $_.samaccountname -match "Administrator") -or ($_.context.name -ne $Computer -and $_.samaccountname -match $OKAccounts))){"X"}}}` bit to a `Where` statement, so that line would be:

```psh
          $group.Members | select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName | Where { !(($_.Server -eq $_.Domain -and $_.samaccountname -match "Administrator") -or ($_.Server -ne $_.Domain -and $_.samaccountname -match $OKAccounts)) }
```

You'll also want to remove the `Flag = ''` lines from your `Catch` and `Else` scriptblocks as well. Which then the code only returns something like:

```psh
Server         Domain                     SamAccountName            
------         ------                     --------------            
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          SomeAcct1                   
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          SomeAcct2
TMTsLab        TMTsTacoTruck.com          TMTech
```

Full function code at that point:

```psh
function get-localgroupmember {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter PC")]
    [string[]]$computername
  )

  BEGIN {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    $ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
    $OKAccounts = ("Workstation Admin","Domain Admins" | ForEach{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
  }

  PROCESS{
    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
      If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
        try {
          $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer
          $idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
          $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')

          $group.Members | select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName | Where{ !(($_.Server -ieq $_.Domain -and $_.samaccountname -match "Administrator") -or ($_.Server -ne $_.Domain -and $_.samaccountname -match $OKAccounts)) }

        } catch {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Domain = "Error"
            Account = "Error"
          }
        }
      } else {
          [pscustomobject] @{
            Server = $computer
            Domain = "Off-Line"
            Account = "Off-Line"
          }
      } 

    } # end foreach
  } # end PROCESS

}
```

Comment: What, you don't like tacos? Fine, next time I'll change it to TMTsChinchillaFarm.com just for you Matt =P